# Can we use class name to call j query date-pickers (in JavaScript file) after cloning a date-picker multiple times with same class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone, datetimepicker

I am using jQuery Bootstrap DateTimePicker to get the date value as an input in my form. In this form, multiple values for same date field is needed.And for that, same datetimepicker input field is cloned with same class name. But when I execute the code, only first datetimepicker works. Other cloned datetimepickers doesn't work.

Is there a solution or an alternative method for this Problem?

*HTML code*

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="emp_date_from">Date From</label>
  <input id="emp_date_from" name="emp_date_from[]" type="text" class="form-control emp_date_from" required="" />
</div>
```

*JavaScript code*

```
jQuery('.emp_date_from').datepicker({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove default datepicker class `hasDatepicker` after clone and reinitialize your datepicker with new instance like below.

```js
$('.emp_date_from').datepicker({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
});

var $section = $(".form-group").clone();
$("#clone").click(function() {
  var $sectionClone = $section.clone();
  $('.wrapper').append($sectionClone);
  var $this = $('.wrapper').find('.emp_date_from');
  initDatepicker();
});

function initDatepicker() {
  $('.wrapper').find('.emp_date_from').each(function(i, e) {
    $(this).removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      autoclose: true,
      todayHighlight: true,
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="emp_date_from">Date From</label>
    <input id="emp_date_from" name="emp_date_from[]" type="text" class="form-control emp_date_from" required="" />
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Clone " id="clone" />
```